# Two-point function of massless scalar theory in 2d CFT

Tags: mathematical-physics, quantum-field-theory, conformal-field-theory

Following the derivation of the massless free-boson two-point function given in Di Francesco, Mathieu and Sènèchal, I had an apparently stupid doubt. Look at the attached picture.

Where does the contribution $\lim_{\rho \rightarrow 0} \rho K'(\rho)$ to the integral in Eq. (2.100) go? Do they suppose it is zero? In this case Eq.(2.101) is not consistent with this requirement.

The only possible explanation I found is that the behaviour in $\rho\sim 0$ is not well-defined but I am not satified.

Any ideas??

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It goes nowhere. The simplification being made between the first and second line is that $$-\int_0^r\frac{\rho}{\rho}\frac{\partial}{\partial \rho}(\rho K^\prime(\rho))~d\rho = -rK^\prime(r).$$

Comment: Do you agree with me that $-\int_0^r\frac{\rho}{\rho}\frac{\partial}{\partial \rho}(\rho K^\prime(\rho))~d\rho = -rK^\prime(r) + \lim_{\rho\rightarrow 0} \rho K'(\rho)$?

Comment: Upon looking more closely, I agree with you. I think there should be an extra factor of 2 in the expression for $K(r)$.